# Margem relativa com variação grande entre browsers

Tags: css, html5, margens

Estou com problemas com margens CSS que levam porcentagem em um projeto responsivo.
Tem objetos que levam margem de 15% referente ao contâiner, e no IE10 e Safari a diferença chega a ser 10% a mais do que deveria. No Chrome e no Firefox esta tudo normal.

Alguém já teve esse problema? e como resolveu?

No jsfiddle não vai conseguir visualizar.

Ex:

```
objeto {
  margin: 15% 0 0 0;
}
```

O resultado é o dobro da distância nos navegadores citados e não ha nenhum objeto div anterior a esse para explicar isso.

Comment: ajude nos a responder postando seu código

Comment: Voce poder da uma exemplo no http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Tem cara de discrepância de box model. Seu HTML tem um doctype no topo? Qual?

Comment: @bfavaretto tinha esquecido da parte da discrepância heheh quase dormindo aqui. Bom, assim sendo, acredito que não há como responder o problema da discrepância sem um maior detalhamento da parte do Helton.

Comment: To usando HTML5 <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: @HeltonSS, um exemplo mínimo que reproduza seu problema vai te ajudar a conseguir respostas de mais qualidade.

Comment: Voce esta usando `* { box-sizing: border-box }` tambem?

Comment: Não estou usando to tentando ver uma forma de demonstra aqui o problema

Comment: Adicionar `* { box-sizing: border-box }`; touvez essa vai ajuda.

Comment: Apenas como teste, inclua o [CSS do Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css) e veja o que acontece.

Comment: @JonathanSampson por incrivel que pareça sua resposta aparenta ter resolvido o problema, hahaha apesar que ela destruiu todo o layout em porcentagem mas os objetos estão se mantendo no lugar, colocar como resposta vou terminar ajustar o layout novamente e faço as devidas considerações, Valeu a todo mundo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No passado, o modelo do `box` era diferente para o Internet Explorer e todos os outros navegadores. Hoje, para todos os teus projectos, é inteligente adicionar o seguinte:

```css
*, :before, :after, ::before, ::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Esta declaração vai-te resolver muitos problemas com o *layout* nos teus projectos.

Comment: Hi there Jonathan, nice to see you around here :) (big fan here) _(comentário a ser removido em breve...)_

Comment: Obrigado, Zuul. Estou tentando melhorar meu Portuguese. Tem nada melhor dq Stack Overflow em Portuguese :)

Answer (score 0):

tenta usar hacks para navegadores
HACK PARA IE 10

```
  <!--[if !IE]><!--><script>if(/*@cc_on!@*/false){document.documentElement.className+=' ie10';}</script><!--<![endif]-->
```

```
.ie10 .objeto{
 margin-top:5%;  /*para tirar a diferença que esta dando a mais*/
}
```

hack para Safari e Chrome
/* Somente para Chrome e Safari */

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 .objeto{ margin-top:5%; } /*para tirar a diferença que esta dando a mais*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar dar um CSS Global Reset, todo *browser* tem prioridades para definir o CSS de uma página.

### A ordem é:

1. CSS inline

   Através do uso do atributo `style` cujo mesmo não recomendo:

   ```html
   <div style=”float:left”>
   ```
2. CSS na página

   Outra coisa que não recomendo, e não vejo necessidade. É quando coloca a TAG `style` dentro da TAG `head`:

   ```html
   <style>
     .publicidade {
       width: 200px;
     }
   </style>
   ```
3. CSS externo

   Esse é o CSS normal, quando invocamos dentro do `head`:

   ```html
   <link href=”home.css” type=”text/css” rel=”stylesheet”/>
   ```
4. CSS definido pelo *browser*

   Sim, isso existe e é isso que nos causa problemas.

---

Quando nenhum CSS é encontrado para um elemento (`div`, `p`, `h1`, `img`, etc..), o navegador coloca por sua conta, qual vai ser o tamanho dos títulos, dos parágrafos, a `margin` entre elementos, a fonte padrão, o `padding` da página, bordas dos elementos, etc…

É aí que entra o CSS Global Reset, que são uma série de propriedades CSS atribuídas a todos os elementos HTML, justamente para retirar o CSS definido pelo *browser*, deixando as propriedades de todos os elementos iguais. Assim reduz drasticamente a diferença entre Firefox, Safari, Internet Explorer, Opera, etc.

Existem diversos CSS Global Reset (normalmente as pessoas colocam alguma coisa a mais para facilitar no seu projeto), mas todos eles variam pouco.

---

### Eu uso esse aqui:

```css
{outline-color:invert;outline-style:none;outline-width:medium;}
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote,
pre,a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
:focus { outline: 0; }
body { line-height: 1; color: black; background: white; font-size:100.01%;}
ol, ul { list-style: none;}
table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0;}
caption, th, td { text-align: left; font-weight: normal;}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after { content: "";}
blockquote, q { quotes: "" "";}
strong{ font-weight: bold; }
body,input,select,textarea { font-size: inherit; }
```

Comment: Mano ja tentei isso tbm.